# Testing REST routes with cURL - data not saving

Tags: mean-stack

I am running through the tutorials in [Open REST Routes](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/opening-rest-routes) but I am now stuck at posting data to the mongodb posts collection.

When I cURL it executes without error but my title and link are not saved and the upvotes defaults to 0 as defined in the schema.

My Post schema is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: String,
   link: String,
   upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
   comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}]
});
mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

I get the result below:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/posts -d '{"title":"Go Bigdadi! Nicely done!!!","link":"http://www.foo.com","upvotes":2}'
{"upvotes":0,"comments":[],"_id":"5b740c875bdf6a326c677cd3","__v":0}`
```

Please suggest where I am likely to be messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out....

I tried changing the parameters round a bit and was able to get the expected result.

I tried:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/posts -i -X POST -d "title=Bigdadi Rules Posts&link=http://www.foo.com&upvotes=2"
```

It works!!!